Are ALL 6 points of Dan, 9:24 inferred in Isaiah 53's:- 1) The person of the Servant, i.e. Messiah; 2)The passion of same; & 3) The portion of same?
It is well established among theologians, past and present, that Isaiah's 53rd Chapter is a foretelling of the future Messiah, in Christ Jesus. The story line commences with Jesus' lowly but all powerful "Personage", which then proceeds through the "Passion", and presupposed "Passivity" of Jesus, which then culminates in his "Proportionality", which speaks to all manner of representation, for the subsequent good of all believers in him and his "Ransom Sacrifice".
It is also a well established fact that at least the first 3 promises, if not 4, decreed for Daniel's people and their holy city, of Daniel 9:24 were concluded at the cross:-

To finish the transgression.
To make and end of Sin.
To make atonement for iniquity.

... but it's not so well established that the remaining 3 aspects, of the angel Gabriel's foretelling, were accomplished as a result of our Lord's sacrifice. These being:-

To bring in everlasting righteousness.
To seal up vision and prophecy.
To anoint the most Holy of Holies.

... and yet, to me, it would seem that the last three verses of Isaiah 53, may well indeed speak to those further accomplishments, once we take into account the (subsequent to the cross) resurrection and then ascension of our Lord, and all that that suggests, culminating in him taking up his seat at the right hand of God, in that most holy heavenly sanctuary. Final and yet future fulfillment not withstanding.

"Inferred" is something that is done by the person reading or hearing the statement. I think your intended meaning requires a different word.

@RayButterworth - You may well be correct. I did have the word "covered" in mind when trying to keep the question title from exceeding the requisite number of syllables, which presented more difficulty than enough, but that seemed too simplistic. I think the body of the Q. gets to the point though.

I am not one of those who votes to close a question because it is "opinion-based" but I would point out that answers will necessarily depend on theological assumptions as well as sound hermeneutics. Jews will certainly give a different answer from Christians, and Christians will disagree with one another... not to mention people such as myself, who hold to the Maccabean hypothesis (which avers that Daniel 9 refers to events in the 2nd century, not the time of Jesus.)

Puzzled at you saying it's not so well established (in those O.T. portions) that the Lord's sacrifice established the bringing in of everlasting righteousness. Isaiah 53:11 calls him God's righteous servant who will justify many by bearing their iniquities. Romans 3:21-22 states that the righteousness of God is manifested by the faith of Jesus Christ (at the time of sacrifice). All the points require the fulfilment in Christ to happen before it all becomes clear, surely?

@Anne - I would tend to agree with you on the righteousness aspect, that's why I said ... if not 4 ... Not sure whether you are implying 1st Century, or 2nd Coming with regard to your last sentence however.

@DanFefferman - It has not escaped my notice that with regard to Daniel 9, you, of all people, hold to the Maccabean hypothesis. An hypothesis that, quite frankly, has  little to no basis in fact and as a consequence is not a widely held belief. Also, if this Q. is to be ascertained to be "opinion-based", then why would I start out the "body" of the Q. with "... It is well established among theologians, past and present ..." And, then also later write "... it would seem ..." and "... may well indeed ..."

I think this sound more like a homiletic question than a hermeneutic question.  A true hermeneutic question would provide some verbal parallels between the two passages which do not exist.

@Dottard - I go weeks without asking a question and then when I think I've found a good one, I get harangued from all sides. I must be out of practice I guess. Hermeneutics:- ... the branch of knowledge that deals with interpretation, especially of the Bible or literary texts... How did I not try to interpret? How did I not try to ask for further considered interpretations?

@OldeEnglish - I apologize if you feel "harangued" - that was not my intention.  The basic premise of hermeneutics is that when linking two passages of scripture there must be some objective basis for doing so.  In this case, I cannot see it.  I accept that I may be stupid or misguided; therefore, if you wish to link the two passages, it would be helpful to provide some definitive basis for doing so.  However, you will need to avoid preaching a too long question.

@Dottard - I just don't know what you mean by "two passages". We have 6 points of conjecture! Where do you get the idea of two passages??

@OldeEnglish - look at your question - Dan 9:24 and Isa 53.

@Dottard - Now I see what you mean. I guess I thought the connection between the two OT books was obvious. I could try and edit but there would seem to be too little interest here. I felt that the Q. was long enough as it was and God forbid that I get too "preachy", as you say, that was certainly not my intention.

Points 4,5, and 6 were also accomplished in Christ's life, death, and resurrection.  Briefly:
4. To bring in everlasting(eternal) righteousness.

[Rom 5:21 ESV] so that, as sin reigned in death, grace also might reign through righteousness leading to eternal life through Jesus Christ our Lord.
This is referenced directly in [Isa 53:11 ESV] Out of the anguish of his soul he shall see and be satisfied; by his knowledge shall the righteous one, my servant, make many to be accounted righteous, and he shall bear their iniquities.
5. To seal up vision and prophecy.

Merriam-Webster's first definition of the verb seal is: to confirm or make secure by or as if by a seal, and its first definition of the noun (not the animal) is: something that confirms, ratifies, or makes secure : guarantee, assurance.  Christ's life demonstrated the certainty of the prophecies (Lk 24:44), in particular by fulfilling so many of them, which assures us that those remaining are secure as well.
I do not see Isa 53 pointing to this.
6. To anoint the most Holy of Holies.

[Act 10:38 ESV] how God anointed Jesus of Nazareth with the Holy Spirit and with power...
I do not see a reference to this in Isa 53, but it is clear in [Isa 61:1 ESV] 1 The Spirit of the Lord GOD is upon me, because the LORD has anointed me to bring good news to the poor; he has sent me to bind up the brokenhearted, to proclaim liberty to the captives, and the opening of the prison to those who are bound;

After 7 weeks (nearly 8) an answer, rather than an objection, and not a bad answer at that. Good for you, + 1. 53:11 does/may indeed cover the righteousness aspect. 53:10 could be speaking to the culmination of vision and prophecy, in that his (Jesus') offspring (believers in Ransom Sacrifice) will benefit. He will prolong his days through being resurrected. 53:12 ... I will allot him a portion with the great ..., would appear to speak to the final point, especially if one considers 52:13, which speaks to Jesus' "ultimate" anointing in the heavenly Holy of Holies.
